# How can i use cloud-init to load a datadisk on an ubuntu VM in azure

Tags: azure, cloud-init

I have been trying use cloud-init to partition and mount a datadisk on a Ubuntu VM in azure. Most of the online examples show how to do that for the temporary disk but not for data disk. I tried dabbling around with it with out much luck. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong in the below code or if its not possible to do it with cloud-init

```
#cloud-config
device_aliases: {'ephemeral0': '/dev/sdb','datadisk': '/dev/sdc1'}

disk_setup:
    ephemeral0:
         table_type: mbr
         layout: True
         overwrite: False
    /dev/sdc1:
         table_type: mbr
         layout: True
         overwrite: False

fs_setup:
    - label: ephemeral0
      filesystem: ext4
      device: ephemeral0.1
      replace_fs: ntfs
    - cmd: mkfs -t %(filesystem)s -L %(label)s %(device)s
      label: '/dev/sdc1/'
      filesystem: ext4
      device: '/dev/sdc1/'
      replace_fs: ntfs

mounts:
    - ["ephemeral0.1", "/mnt"]
    - ["/dev/sdc1/", "/datadisk"]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I agree -- not many examples of this common scenario. I think part of the problem you're facing above is that you're referencing a partition instead of a disk in disk_setup.

With Azure, the first data disk attached to the VM will usually be identified as `/dev/sdc`, the second will be `/dev/sdd`, and so on. This isn't guaranteed, however. The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-device-names-problems) indicates that there are circumstances which can result in a different drive letter being assigned. As a result, we'll reference the disks using a build-in alias. This alias is guarantee to always be mapped using the LUN assigned in the ARM template (or disk definition). These aliases follow the form `/dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun#` (with partitions aliased as `/dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun#-part#`).

If you're using ARM, the template will include a reference in the VM definition to the drive. As part of that definition, you will specify the LUN value. You can reference that assigned value in your cloud-init. For example, the following ARM snippet will create `/dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0`:

```
"dataDisks": [
{
    "lun": 0,
    "name": "[concat(variables('vmName'),'-datadisk0')]",
    "createOption": "Attach",
    "managedDisk":
    {
        "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/disks/', 
                concat(variables('vmName'),'-datadisk0'))]"
    }
},
```

Knowing this, we can construct the contents for a cloud-config. First, we define the data disk. I suggest using GPT as the table type for to enable support for disks and partitions that are > 2TiB.

```
disk_setup:
    /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0:
        table_type: gpt
        layout: True
        overwrite: True
```

Next, we specify the file system setup for the disks. We reference each partition and declare the file system to be used.

```
fs_setup:
    - device: /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0
      partition: 1
      filesystem: ext4
```

Finally, we mount the partitions. The process used by cloud-init will create the folders and mount the specified partitions. I'm using the recommended `nofail` (ensures the VM can boot in the event of issues or a detached drive) along with `noexec` (which prevents executing binaries on that partition). Since we've placed the file system on the first partition of lun0, we need to mount `lun0-part1`.

```
mounts:
    - ["/dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0-part1", "/datadisk", auto, "defaults,noexec,nofail"]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10947993/ken-muse do you have similar write-up for mounting Azure filesystem and not disk? let me knowif you want me to post a question about it, I'll defo vote it up :)

Comment: Awesome write up!  Do you know how this would work if I redeployed the VM and the data disk already had a partition?  I used Terraform and sometimes we destroy the server for a clean build test, but want to keep the data disk.

Comment: Did anybody try this in conjunction terraform? In my case, the disk gets attached way after (~20s) the disk_setup module ran, causing it to fail.