# Using cloud-init on an Azure VM to mount a data disk fails

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, azure-virtual-machine, cloud-init

This is a similar problem to a previous SO question, from which I adapted my code [How can i use cloud-init to load a datadisk on an ubuntu VM in azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808638/how-can-i-use-cloud-init-to-load-a-datadisk-on-an-ubuntu-vm-in-azure)

Using a cloud-config file passed through Terraform:

```yaml
#cloud-config
disk_setup:
  /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0:
    table_type: gpt
    layout: true
    overwrite: false

fs_setup:
  - device: /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0
    partition: 1
    filesystem: ext4

mounts:
  - [
      "/dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0-part1",
      "/opt/data",
      auto,
      "defaults,noexec,nofail",
    ]
```

```
data "template_file" "cloudconfig" {
  template = file("${path.module}/cloud-init.tpl")
}

data "template_cloudinit_config" "config" {
  gzip          = true
  base64_encode = true

  part {
    content_type = "text/cloud-config"
    content      = "${data.template_file.cloudconfig.rendered}"
  }
}

module "nexus_test_vm" {
  #unnecessary details ommitted - 1 VM with 1 external disk, fixed lun of 0, ubuntu 18.04
  vm_size            = "Standard_B2S"

  cloud_init_template = data.template_cloudinit_config.config.rendered
}
```

Relevant bit of the module (VM creation)

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "generic-vm" {
  count               = var.number
  name                = "${local.my_name}-${count.index}-vm"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  network_interface_ids         = [azurerm_network_interface.generic-nic[count.index].id]
  vm_size                       = var.vm_size
  delete_os_disk_on_termination = true

  storage_image_reference {
    id = var.image_id
  }

  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "${local.my_name}-${count.index}-os"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
    disk_size_gb      = var.os_disk_size
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "${local.my_name}-${count.index}"
    admin_username = local.my_admin_user_name
    custom_data    = var.cloud_init_template
  }

  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true

    ssh_keys {
      path = "/home/${local.my_admin_user_name}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      //key_data = tls_private_key.vm_ssh_key.public_key_openssh
      key_data = var.public_key_openssh
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "${local.my_name}-${count.index}"
    Deployment  = local.my_deployment
    Prefix      = var.prefix
    Environment = var.env
    Location    = var.location
    Volatile    = var.volatile
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_managed_disk" "generic-disk" {
  name                 = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.generic-vm.*.name[0]}-1-generic-disk"
  location             = var.rg_location
  resource_group_name  = var.rg_name
  storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  create_option        = "Empty"
  disk_size_gb         = var.external_disk_size
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment" "generic-disk" {
  managed_disk_id    = azurerm_managed_disk.generic-disk.id
  virtual_machine_id = azurerm_virtual_machine.generic-vm.*.id[0]
  lun                = 0
  caching            = "ReadWrite"
}
```

I am getting a lot of weird errors indicating that the disk does not exist when cloud-init is running. However, when I ssh into the VM, the disk is right there! Is this a race condition? Is there a wait I can configure in cloud-init or something to give me a better picture of what might be happening?

Relevant logs from the VM:

#### head -n 5000 /var/log/cloud-init.log | grep lun

```
2020-04-07 16:30:51,296 - cc_disk_setup.py[DEBUG]: Partitioning disks: {'/dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0': {'layout': True, 'overwrite': False, 'table_type': 'gpt'}, '/dev/disk/cloud/azure_resource': {'table_type': 'gpt', 'layout': [100], 'overwrite': True, '_origname': 'ephemeral0'}}
2020-04-07 16:30:51,318 - util.py[DEBUG]: Creating partition on /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0 took 0.021 seconds
Device /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0 did not exist and was not created with a udevadm settle.
Device /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0 did not exist and was not created with a udevadm settle.
RuntimeError: Device /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0 did not exist and was not created with a udevadm settle.
2020-04-07 16:30:51,601 - cc_disk_setup.py[DEBUG]: setting up filesystems: [{'device': '/dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0', 'filesystem': 'ext4', 'partition': 1}]
2020-04-07 16:30:51,725 - util.py[DEBUG]: Creating fs for /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0 took 0.124 seconds
Device /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0 did not exist and was not created with a udevadm settle.
Device /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0 did not exist and was not created with a udevadm settle.
RuntimeError: Device /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0 did not exist and was not created with a udevadm settle.
2020-04-07 16:30:51,733 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: mounts configuration is [['/dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0-part1', '/opt/data', 'auto', 'defaults,noexec,nofail']]
2020-04-07 16:30:51,734 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Attempting to determine the real name of /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0-part1
2020-04-07 16:30:51,734 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: changed /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0-part1 => None
2020-04-07 16:30:51,734 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Ignoring nonexistent named mount /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0-part1
2020-04-07 16:30:51,736 - cc_mounts.py[DEBUG]: Changes to fstab: ['+ /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0-part1 /opt/data auto defaults,noexec,nofail,comment=cloudconfig 0 2']
```

#### ls -l /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Apr  7 16:32 /dev/disk/azure/scsi1/lun0 -> ../../../sdc
```

Comment: Can you show the content of the module you create?

Comment: Updated with the relevant part of the module

Comment: I didn't see any storage_data_disk in the virtual machine. How do you attach the data disk to the VM?

Comment: Added that too!

Comment: OK, I saw it. You use the association to attach the data disk. I think the sequence is the problem. You can try to add the data disk inside the VM resource with the block `storage_data_disk`.

Comment: giving that a shot now. if that's the problem i'll report it in the azure provider, so they can either fix it or at least add a note in the documentation

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, but it should be shown in a note.

Comment: that did the trick! can you reply with it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I added the answer to display it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this issue, I think it's the sequence about the data disk and the VM and the cloud-init. As I know, the cloud-init is executed when the VM first boot. And the Terraform file you created seems that the data disk may be created later than the VM, so it also is later than then cloud-init and then it caused the error.

So the solution is that set the data disk inside the VM with the `storage_data_disk` block so that the VM will be created with the data disk attached and then execute the cloud-init.